How to check if strides N-d array is contiguous
I have a class that represents an N-dimensional array (similar to an OpenCV Mat, or an Numpy array).
It has two N-vectors: its shape and its stride.
The shape determines the size of the array on each axis (i.e. width/height/depth).
The stride determines its memory layout: Going from array[i, j, k, l] to array[i, j+1, k, l] advances the memory address by stride[1] (because index of the second (1) axis is incremented.)
For example if the array is 2D and contains a 640x480 image, that is stored in row-major order (meaning the pixels on a same row are next to each other in memory), it would have shape=[480, 640] and strides=[640, 1].
In col-major it would have strides=[1, 480].
In both these cases, the strides are such that its memory is a contiguous region, where each address contains a pixel. But the strides could also be set such that there is padding after lines/columns or between pixels, so that it is no longer contiguous.
Is there a simple algorithm to determine, in the N-dimensional case, whether given shape and strides form a contiguous array?
